# Glint Administration -- What Steps to take to claim my assets?

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, gold

I have the issue that the company Glint (https://glintpay.com) has gone into administration and all customers' assets, including mine, are frozen by the administrators. Glint is a company that mainly invests in gold on customers' behalf. The terms and conditions state clearly that customers assets are held separately in another account, and no matter what happens to Glint and its partners, customers funds are safe and moreover, that customer has the right to terminate their account and withdraw the assets at any time.
The frequency of updates from administrators has gone down, and in the last of the updates, they talk about an option that if the company ceases to exist, they will redistribute the gold and deduct all redistribution fees from customers assets.

Reference for terms and conditions : [Terms and conditions](https://glintpay.com/terms-of-use/)

Not only would I like to withdraw all my assets and close my account now, I think moreover, since they are already violating customers rights, instead a commission or interest for breaching the law could be demanded from them.

1. Are any of you also gold investors with Glint?
2. Does anyone have any opinion on the company [Glint] ? What would you do?
   Would you turn to a legal office? If yes, then which one?

Please advise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about legal process rather than personal finance.